# TSQL method to select rows not in a base table as an alternative to UNION?

Tags: sql-server, row, union

I saw a method that exists in SQL Server somewhere but i am not able to find it again...

It simplifies the following SQL logic:

```
SELECT 'CategoryA','DescriptionA'
UNION
SELECT 'CategoryB','DescriptionB'
UNION
SELECT 'CategoryC','DescriptionC'
```

To something like this:

```
SELECT ROWS(('CategoryA','DescriptionA'), 
            ('CategoryB', 'DescriptionB'), 
            ('CategoryC', 'DescriptionC'))
```

Can anyone tell me what that feature could be and its syntax?

Comment: maybe you have seen it in a context of insert / values ?: Declare @a Table (i1 int,i2 int)
Insert into @a Values (1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(6,7),(8,9)
Select * from @a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use a [Table Value Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES ( 'CategoryA', 'DescriptionA'),
             ( 'CategoryB', 'DescriptionB'),
             ( 'CategoryC', 'DescriptionC')) V(Col1, Col2)
```

NB: This has the same semantics as `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`  though you could always `SELECT DISTINCT` from it.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Altought i has a 1000 row limit in contrast with UNION that i think supports a lot more.